# Translating "Most Games Played" Accurately?

Tags: traducción

What's the best translation for Most Games Played in terms of video games?

Comment: Is the context a list or group of different games? Or the different times you've played the same game?

Comment: A bit more detail to answer this question would be good. Under what context would you use that sentence? I just can see it in a ranking with users, and you have the user that played the Most times, the translation for that is "Más juegos jugados". Or did you mean "Most Played Games"?, basically the games that are played the most, in which case the translation is "Juegos más jugados".

Answer (score 5):

Maybe there is a confusion here. Just in case, the translation would be:

`Most Games Played` -> `La mayoría de juegos/videojuegos jugados`

`Most Played Games` -> `Juegos/Videojuegos más jugados`

Answer (score 2):

The most accurate translation for me would be:

`Juegos más jugados` or `Videojuegos más jugados`.

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm tricky one because Spanish doesn't differentiate between "Games" (Juegos) and "Play" (Jugar) as you can see, it is the same for the verb (Jugar) and the pronoun (Juego), and in Spanish redundancy (use of similar words in a sentence) is not recommended (but allowed). In this way the sentence "Juegos más jugados" it is just a little not common but allowed. Another one could be "Juegos más usados". As an example, it would be common hear "Candy Crush es uno de los juegos más usados hoy en día" (Candy Crush is on of the most played games nowadays".

Answer (score 0):

It could also refer to the number of times you have played a specific game: For example, in soccer, or football, you'd say "he's played most of the games in the season".

In this case,

> Most games played -> Más partidos jugados

If it were a videogame or boardgame, then the word "partida" is used, and so

> Most games played -> Más partidas jugadas

This is complementary to the other answers, but I think this last answer is the one you're looking for

EDIT: Responding to the comment below. No, not really. Again, look at my example: "He's played 15 games this season", talking about sports, doesn't mean 15 different games, but 15 different matches. So, in some contexts, game would be translated to partido/partida

Comment: game is just "juego". partido/partida would be match.

Comment: @Omar "game" is widely used synonym of "match", but I agree with you that this is not what the OP meant.

Answer (score 0):

The straight translation, taking into account you're talking about videogames, would be:

> Más juegos jugados

(meaning, someone played more games than anyone else, "más" here is not used in the comparative sense "más que")

Translating it as "La mayoría de los juegos jugados", as is proposed in another answer supposes that you're really trying to translate the sentence "Most OF THE games played". That could be true in a casual setting. You would need to provide a bit more information on where you're finding this sentence